# How to pull out image url on a page in wordpress?

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress

Does anyone know how to pull out the url of the image in wordpress so it can be used as a refrence in the script? I need to pull them dynamically. However when I'm using postimage(); it pulls out this:

```
<a href="address">
<img width="300" height="300" src="image.png" class="image" alt="" title="LINKING"/>
</a>
```

I'm only interested in src. Does anyone know how to pull it out? Thx in advance

Comment: How exactly are you trying to extract the URL right now?

Comment: I was thinking of doing some sub string function, but I really hate that idea cause the code would look just horrible. There surely must be a function in wp that allows u extract image url. Just like pulling out the title title();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this code in the loop:

```
$thumbnail = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID));
echo $thumbnail[0];
```